# Moment picker view not changing to 12hr format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm having trouble making the view to 12 hr format. I've used [angular-moment-picker](https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker) library for this.

[image]

What I want is to turn the view to 12hr format.

**html**

```
<div class="input-group" moment-picker="ctrl.timepicker" format="hh:mm a">
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
</span>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Select a time" ng-model="ctrl.timepicker" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
</div>
```

**config**

```
function momentPickerProvider(momentPickerProvider) {
  momentPickerProvider.options({
    minutesFormat: 'hh:mm'
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you create plunker of your code?

Comment: Have you tried minutesFormat: 'hh:mm a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
app.config(['momentPickerProvider', function(momentPickerProvider){
  momentPickerProvider.options({
    hoursFormat: 'hh:mm'
  });
}])
```